# relation between mouse cursor and sql cursor

Tags: sql, cursor

I'm a rookie in software development.
I'm curious because of the name, Is there any relation between the Cursor in SQL and the Mouse Cursors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is NO!

Comment: No, a cursor in SQL is a database object to manipulate data on a row-by-row basis

Comment: At least they both point to the certain position in some data array :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, it does indeed "point" to certain objects in the data base but that's pretty much the only similarity. I would say the cursor is closer to an Iterator.
Cursor are used to to perform operations on retrieved records. This can be done with the SELECT command on SQL language.